# XML to CSV using XSLT node values not showing up

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am a newbie and writing an XSLT transformation from XML to CSV. Below is the output file that it should look like (Desired result):

```
21072,Charles,Bradley,401K,377.96
21072,Charles,Bradley,401K-R,94.49
21082,Alex,Grossman,401K,10657.15
3,11129.6
```

but I am getting this and not sure how to get the counts and total and also exclude rows that are 401(k) T completely.

```
21072,Charles,Bradley,401(k) [USA],377.96,
401(k) Roth [USA],94.49,
401(k) T,94.49,
21082,Alex,Grossman,401(k) [USA],10657.15,
401(k) T,10657.15,
```

I have tried this following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR-TestReport" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs wd"
    version="2.0">    
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
    <xsl:param name="linefeed" select="'&#13;&#10;'"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="DetailRecords"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="TrailerRecord"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Builds Detail Records -->
    <xsl:template name="DetailRecords">

        <xsl:for-each select = "wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Employee_ID"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:First_Name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Last_Name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:for-each select = "wd:Payroll_Result_Lines">
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:Deduction/@wd:Descriptor"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
                <xsl:value-of select = "wd:Result_Line_Amount"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>            
           <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>

           </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

    <!--Builds Trailer Record -->
    <xsl:template name="TrailerRecord">

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

for this XML file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR-TestReport">
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Employee_ID>21072</wd:Employee_ID>
    <wd:Last_Name>Bradley</wd:Last_Name>
    <wd:First_Name>Charles</wd:First_Name>
    <wd:Payroll_Result_Lines>
        <wd:Deduction wd:Descriptor="401(k) [USA]">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">ff68c0f1227c41a2a5221f6a7e6a67e5</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Deduction_Code">401K</wd:ID>
        </wd:Deduction>
        <wd:Result_Line_Amount>377.96</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
    </wd:Payroll_Result_Lines>
    <wd:Payroll_Result_Lines>
        <wd:Deduction wd:Descriptor="401(k) Roth [USA]">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">2d277641684a48fb861a896e4eeb3eea</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Deduction_Code">401K-R</wd:ID>
        </wd:Deduction>
        <wd:Result_Line_Amount>94.49</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
    </wd:Payroll_Result_Lines>
    <wd:Payroll_Result_Lines>
        <wd:Deduction wd:Descriptor="401(k) T">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">2d277641684a48fb861a896e4eeb3eea</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Deduction_Code">401K-T</wd:ID>
        </wd:Deduction>
        <wd:Result_Line_Amount>94.49</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
    </wd:Payroll_Result_Lines>
</wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Employee_ID>21082</wd:Employee_ID>
    <wd:Last_Name>Grossman</wd:Last_Name>
    <wd:First_Name>Alex</wd:First_Name>
    <wd:Payroll_Result_Lines>
        <wd:Deduction wd:Descriptor="401(k) [USA]">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">ff68c0f1227c41a2a5221f6a7e6a67e5</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Deduction_Code">401K</wd:ID>
        </wd:Deduction>
        <wd:Result_Line_Amount>10657.15</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
    </wd:Payroll_Result_Lines>
    <wd:Payroll_Result_Lines>
        <wd:Deduction wd:Descriptor="401(k) T">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">ff68c0f1227c41a2a5221f6a7e6a67e5</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Deduction_Code">401K-T</wd:ID>
        </wd:Deduction>
        <wd:Result_Line_Amount>10657.15</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
    </wd:Payroll_Result_Lines>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Comment: Could you explain the required logic in words? E.g. I want yo have a row for each ___ and in each row I want to have these values: ___ .

Comment: Hi, Here is the requirements, the output will be a comma delimited file 
with each record outputting on a separate line.

1.The detail records should contain the following fields (in this order):
Employee ID
First Name
Last Name
Deduction Code
Result Line Amount

The trailer record should contain this data (in this order):
Total number of records on the file
Total amount on the file
2.Remove payroll results with a deduction code of ‘401K-T’.  Update your code to exclude these records.

Thanks,Srini

Answer (score 1):

As you use XSLT 2 to create the CSV I would suggest to exploit `xsl:value-of separator` to "construct" a line or record in your CSV

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/CR-TestReport"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR-TestReport"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
    <xsl:param name="linefeed" select="'&#13;&#10;'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="rows" select="//Report_Entry/Payroll_Result_Lines[Deduction[not(ID[@wd:type = 'Deduction_Code'] = '401K-T')]]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$rows"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="count($rows), sum($rows/Result_Line_Amount)" separator="{$separator}"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Payroll_Result_Lines">
      <xsl:value-of select="../(Employee_ID, First_Name, Last_Name), Deduction/@wd:Descriptor, Result_Line_Amount" separator="{$separator}"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYiE

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result, you can change your template to the following.

```
<!--Builds Detail Records -->
<xsl:template name="DetailRecords">
    <xsl:for-each select = "wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">
        <xsl:for-each select = "wd:Payroll_Result_Lines[wd:Deduction/wd:ID[@wd:type='Deduction_Code'] != '401K-T']">
            <xsl:value-of select="../wd:Employee_ID"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../wd:First_Name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../wd:Last_Name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Deduction/wd:ID[@wd:type='Deduction_Code']"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:value-of select = "wd:Result_Line_Amount"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>            
       <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Payroll_Result_Lines[wd:Deduction/wd:ID[@wd:type='Deduction_Code'] != '401K-T'])"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>            
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Payroll_Result_Lines[wd:Deduction/wd:ID[@wd:type='Deduction_Code'] != '401K-T']/wd:Result_Line_Amount)"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

**Its result is:**

```
21072,Charles,Bradley,401K,377.96,
21072,Charles,Bradley,401K-R,94.49,
21082,Alex,Grossman,401K,10657.15,
3,11129.6
```

Comment: Thank you so much zx485, It is working now I have removed the trailer record template from my XSLT based on your code

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment, but I got the same answer as @zx485 except that I removed the terminating seperator. The desired result above doesn't have the trailing comma for each row:

```
            <xsl:value-of select = "wd:Result_Line_Amount"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

I hope this helps and wanted to share - I'm new to SO, so not sure of best way to provide since zx's answer was so close.